# Configure Dspace In Eclipse Luna

Tags: maven-2, eclipse-luna, dspace

How to configuring DSpace-1.7.0 in Eclipse Luna?

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I configured this project using maven in eclipse ,i followed all the steps to configure the project and added all the jar files required still i'm unable to run the project.
steps i followed :

Import in Existing Maven Projects -> dspace-1.7.0-src-release / dspace-jspui

structure i got in package explorer is 
>dspace-jspui
>dspace-jspui-api
>Servers
>dspace-jspui-webapp


is this the correct way to import such project in eclipse or any modification required,because its showing error mark for every sub folder i mentioned above
thanks \

Answer (score 0):

File -> import -> Projects from git
Clone URI

paste uri (https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace)

import as general proyect.

next back to dspace 1.7

over proyect -> rigth button -> team -> switch to.. -> Remote -> tags -> dspace-1.7.0 ( try to upgrade to 1.7.3) checkout

next do a maven eclipse:eclipse to generate java proyects
And re-import proyect:

File -> import -> existing proyect. -> import existing proyects

Comment: Hi Adan,

 After pasting URI : (https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace) in Source Git Repository page it requires Authentication information:
  
 1) User:
 2) Password:
 
 Thanks

Comment: Hi Adan, how to get User name and Password?

Comment: do you try to click "next" button without insert an user and password?

Comment: Thanks Adan 

process is done up to checkout.after checkout get structure of package Explorer like-

/DSpace[DSpace dspace-1_73]
/DSpace
/DSpace/dspace
/DSpace/dspace-api
/DSpace/dspace-discovery
/DSpace/dspace-jspui
/DSpace/dspace-lni
/DSpace/dspace-oai
/DSpace/dspace-stats
/DSpace/dspace-sword
/DSpace/dspace-xmlui
   LICENSE
   LICENSE_HEADER
   NOTICE
   pom.xml
   README

after that what exactly do?

next do a maven eclipse:eclipse to generate java proyects And re-import proyect:
File -> import -> existing proyect. -> import existing proyects

Comment: Hi Adan,

when run the /DSpace/dspace-jspui - Home.jsp page not get the output?